Access ThemeData property inside ThemeData definition
In my Flutter app I declare ThemeData with a colorSchemeSeed:
return MaterialApp(
  ...
  theme: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
    colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blueGrey,
    ...
    floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
      backgroundColor: ?
    ),
  ),
  ...
);

I would like to redefine the backgroundColor of the FloatingActionButton using tertiaryContainer color.
Anywhere else in the code I can set this property to FloatingActionButton:
backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiaryContainer,

However, I would like to redefine this property directly in the theme declaration, so that I don't have to do it everywhere and so that I don't define a widget on purpose.
It's possible to do it? If yes, in what way?
Thanks in advance!

You can define a first variable theme and reuse it:
final theme = ThemeData(
  useMaterial3: true,
  visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
  colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blueGrey,
);
MaterialApp(
  return theme.copyWith(
    floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
      backgroundColor: theme.colorScheme.tertiaryContainer,
      ),
  ),
);


I'd say the proper way to do it without relying on a predefined variable is to use Builder as the child of the MaterialApp and get access to the inherited theme by using Theme.of(context).
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
    colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blueGrey,
  ),
  home: Builder(builder: (context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Theme(
      data: theme.copyWith(
        floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
          backgroundColor: theme.colorScheme.tertiaryContainer,
        ),
      ),
      child: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }),
);

Or instead of using Builder, we can also create a new StatelessWidget that serves as the theme modifier before inserting the actual app into the widget tree (as the child of that widget).
Although sure, the shared variable approach works too.
